# What should be the statement in main function that give correct output

Tags: java, tree, queue, binary-tree

Problem Statement:
As per the problem there is a binary tree whose root node 3 left child 9, right child 20, when 20 act as a root node its left child 15, right child 7. 9 has no child.  So structure looks [3,9,20,null,null,15,7].

Find the level order traversal in this binary tree. [Level order traversal/ Breadth - first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_search)

Output: [

[3],

[9,20],

[15,7]

]

To implement this method I create a tree structure like

```
 class TreeNode {
       int val;
       TreeNode left;
       TreeNode right;
       TreeNode(int x) {
           val = x;
       }
  }
```

I also create another class which return this output list

```
class Solution102{

    public List<List<Integer>> levelOrder(TreeNode root){

    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
       //function body
       return result;
    }
}
```

Difficulty arise in main function.

Main function structure

```
public class Q102 {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Solution102 obj102=new Solution102();
        obj102.levelOrder(new TreeNode(3));
        obj102.levelOrder(new TreeNode(9));
        obj102.levelOrder(new TreeNode(20));
        obj102.levelOrder(new TreeNode(null));
        obj102.levelOrder(new TreeNode(null));
        obj102.levelOrder(new TreeNode(15));
        obj102.levelOrder(new TreeNode(7));
        System.out.println(obj102.levelOrder());//error

    }
}
```

`System.out.println(obj102.levelOrder());` in this statement what is the value that I sent within `()` to get a output `List of List`.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Does your `Solution102` class has a method `levelOrder` with no arguments in the signature?

Comment: Your solution does not implement a binary tree. So better look into how to implement binary trees

Comment: @uneq95 `public List<List<Integer>> levelOrder(TreeNode root)` Argument type TreeNode root. TreeNode is another class.

Comment: @Mark My question is not implementation basis. I want to know that I have three class. I create an object `obj102`of class Solution102.When the object call the method levelOrder which take an argument type TreeNode how could I call it? My problem is implementing main function.

Comment: @Encipher That is your main problem. You must correctly implement the binary tree before you do the levelOrder. That is why you are having that error. I think you do not know how a binary tree works and how level order works.

Comment: @Encipher Your code gave me a headache buddy. You seriously need to consider learning about Methods & Return Statements. You need to learn to implement & construct DS like graphs & trees before you try to solve this problem. I feel that this is somehow your homework project.

Answer (score 0):

I am ignoring your tree and level order traversal implementation. According to the code you have posted here, your class `Solution102` only has a method with signature `List<List<Integer>> levelOrder(TreeNode root)`, which is why you were able to do this - `obj102.levelOrder(new TreeNode(3));`

To make a call - `obj102.levelOrder()`, you must have a method defined in your `Solution102` class with signature - `List<List<Integer>> levelOrder()`.

This is just Java stuff I am talking about. Your solution to the actual problem looks messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Solution102 class has no method of levelOrder(). you have to overload your levelOrder method with no argument in the Solution102.
like:-----

```
public String levelOrder(){
     return "Now I am working";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code:

- `obj102.levelOrder(new TreeNode(null));`: You cannot assign null to an Integer. This is the same for the next line too.
- `System.out.println(obj102.levelOrder());`: The `levelOrder()` method expects a parameter and you haven't given one.
- You are not constructing the `result` List of Lists
- You are repeatedly returning List of Lists every time you call the `levelOrder()` method

My Solution:

- Do not feed the `TreeNode` with `null`. Instead, feed it with some large negative number.
- Add a method in `TreeNode` which returns `val` when called. Why you ask?
- In the `levelOrder()` method of `Solution102` class, check if the `TreeNode` contains the large negative number you had used instead of `null` via the `val` returning method. If it matches leave a void in the List of List. Else, just put in the value into the List of List
- Control the `levelOrder()` method's return statement by setting a criterion.

My Suggestions:

- Learn about [Graphs & Trees](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/graph-representation/tutorial/) and learn how to construct them programmatically
- Learn more about return statements, classes & methods